# Is it possible to share particular view/component using WebRTC in React native(iOS and Android)?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, webrtc

I want to share a view/component data to other devices using WebRTC. WebRTC provides *getDisplayMedia* which actually starts screen sharing, so instead of sharing the whole screen can we share a particular view/component with others?